# Google map API Key restrictions does not recognize website IP

Tags: google-maps

I created a wordpress website and I use google map API. I would like to add restrictions to prevent troubles. So I get the IP of the website from my hosting services and I also ping it to double check. I added it on the list of authorized IP but I still have an error message (Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError) and it is impossible to display a card.

I can't understand what am I missing there.
To be precise, it was working fine when I was on local, i was just adding my IP address in the white list.

Also, the website works great if I use no restriction.

Any Ideas? Thank you for your help

Comment: JavaScript code runs in the user's browser on the user's device. So if you're using the JavaScript API in the browser the IP address would be the user's IP. So if you want to restrict usage of the JavaScript API you should do it based on domain.

Comment: Thank you for your help Jacob I understand now. I started by using domain based restrictions and it was almost good except that one page of my website have a form with a button calling a route which call the google map API and it doesn't work if I use domain name restrictions even if I add the specific url to the white list. I should probably create another question for that problem. Thank you again

Comment: Well this is all off topic for WordPress so you should post your question elsewhere, but if you’re _also_ making a request from your server then you should create a separate key for that and use IP restriction for that key.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42167695/api-key-browser-api-keys-cannot-have-referer-restrictions-when-used-with-this-ap and that was the solution I was looking for. Thank you for your answers, it really helped